# How to change width of table with a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know how to re size a table if the window gets bellow 1050px its width needs to be 1050px. If it is above 1050px it needs to be at a width of 100%.

This isnt working so far.

```
window.onresize = resize() {
 var bigger=document.getElementById("menuwrapper");
  if (windowSize < 1050) {
    bigger.width="1050px";
    } 
  else {
    bigger.width="100%";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not CSS `min-width: 1050px;`?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with CSS:

```
#menuwrapper {
    width:100%;
    min-width:1050px;
}
```